# how to call another function only after data is loaded from firebase in js?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is code is generating automatically a pdf on redirecting to download page. I'm using jsPDF lib for generating a pdf file. The problem is loading data from firebase taking time, due to the pdf is generating with empty values.I need to call pdf generation function after loading data from firebase. So that pdf file generates with values in it.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<style>
    .temp_log{
        margin-left: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 19px;
    }    


th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>

<body>
    <button onclick="genPDF()">Generate</button>
      <ul>
          <li>
            <div class ="patient-details">
              <h1 >Patient Details</h1>
              <img src="assets/img/boy.png" alt="image not found">
              <div>
             <h4>Patient Name: John Son</h4>
             <h4>Age: 24</h4>
             <h4>Blood Group: A+</h4>
             <h4>Phone No: +91-7310778879</h4>
             </div>
            </div>
          </li>
    </ul>



   <table border="1">
           <tr>
             <th>Pluse</th>
            </tr>
        <th id="hearbeat_prev"></th>
    </table>


      <table border="1" class="temp_log">
           <tr>
             <th>Temp</th>
            </tr>
        <th id="temp_prev"></th>
    </table>

</body> 
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script> 
  var config = {
    apiKey: "**************",
    authDomain: "********",
    databaseURL: "********",
    projectId: "*******",
    storageBucket: "********",
    messagingSenderId: "*******"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>








<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="assets/js/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/html2pdf.js"></script>


<script>

    heartbeat_previous_data();
    temperature_prev_data();
function temperature_prev_data()
{
    var data ="data: "
    console.log("inside temp 10");

    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("temp");
     rootRef.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function(snap)
          {
        var temp = snap.child("fahrenheit").val();
         console.log(temp);
         document.getElementById("temp_prev").innerHTML += temp +" F" +"<br>";



     });

}


function heartbeat_previous_data()
{
     var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("pulse");  

    var data = "data: ";
    var valid = false;
    var test = 0 ;

    rootRef.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function(snap) {


    var heart = snap.child("rate").val();
         console.log(heart);


        document.getElementById("hearbeat_prev").innerHTML += heart +" "+ "BPM"+ "<br>";



    });

}
    </script>
<script>



        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        var canvas = pdf.canvas;
        canvas.height = 72 * 11;
        canvas.width=72 * 8.5;;
        // var width = 400;
        html2pdf(document.body, pdf, function(pdf) {
                var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.setAttribute('style','position:absolute;right:0; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%; width:500px');
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                iframe.src = pdf.output('datauristring');
            }
        );


    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the code for the genPDF function??

Comment: Check the last script tag it contains pdf generation functions

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a timeout and reset it every time when you append something in the DOM and when data appending is done, it will run your pdf related functions. See the update code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<style>
  .temp_log {
    margin-left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 19px;
  }

  th,
  td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
  }

  th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <button onclick="genPDF()">Generate</button>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="patient-details">
        <h1>Patient Details</h1>
        <img src="assets/img/boy.png" alt="image not found">
        <div>
          <h4>Patient Name: John Son</h4>
          <h4>Age: 24</h4>
          <h4>Blood Group: A+</h4>
          <h4>Phone No: +91-7310778879</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>



  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Pluse</th>
    </tr>
    <th id="hearbeat_prev"></th>
  </table>


  <table border="1" class="temp_log">
    <tr>
      <th>Temp</th>
    </tr>
    <th id="temp_prev"></th>
  </table>

</body>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  var config = {
    apiKey: "**************",
    authDomain: "********",
    databaseURL: "********",
    projectId: "*******",
    storageBucket: "********",
    messagingSenderId: "*******"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>








<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="assets/js/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/html2pdf.js"></script>


<script>
  heartbeat_previous_data();
  temperature_prev_data();

  var waitTimeout = null

  function checkDone() {
    clearTimeout(waitTimeout)
    waitTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
      var canvas = pdf.canvas;
      canvas.height = 72 * 11;
      canvas.width = 72 * 8.5;;
      // var width = 400;
      html2pdf(document.body, pdf, function(pdf) {
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.setAttribute('style', 'position:absolute;right:0; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%; width:500px');
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.src = pdf.output('datauristring');
      });
    }, 300)
  }

  function temperature_prev_data() {
    var data = "data: "
    console.log("inside temp 10");

    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("temp");
    rootRef.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function(snap) {
      var temp = snap.child("fahrenheit").val();
      console.log(temp);
      document.getElementById("temp_prev").innerHTML += temp + " F" + "<br>";
      checkDone()
    });
  }


  function heartbeat_previous_data() {
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("pulse");

    var data = "data: ";
    var valid = false;
    var test = 0;

    rootRef.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function(snap) {

      var heart = snap.child("rate").val();
      console.log(heart);

      document.getElementById("hearbeat_prev").innerHTML += heart + " " + "BPM" + "<br>";
      checkDone()
    });
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calls to the Firebase database are asynchronous and since you are apparently triggering different calls in parallel you should wait that all these different calls are finished in order to start generating the PDF.

Each call returns a promise, therefore you have to use the Promise.all() method ( see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to implement this pattern.

Can you show more info on your genPDF function?

---

EDIT:

1/ Transform the two functions that call Firebase in such a way they return a Promise

```
function temperature_prev_data() {
....
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("temp");
return rootRef.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function(snap) {   //note the return
    var temp = snap.child("fahrenheit").val();
     console.log(temp);
     document.getElementById("temp_prev").innerHTML += temp +" F" +"<br>";
 });
}
```

and

```
function heartbeat_previous_data() {
 ....
  return rootRef.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function(snap) {
   ....
  });
}
```

2/ Add the two Promises to an array then call Promises.all

```
function generatePDF() {
    var promises = [];
    promises.push(temperature_prev_data());
    promises.push(heartbeat_previous_data());
    return Promise.all(promises);
})
```

3/ Call this function and when it has resolved call the PDF generation

```
generatePDF()
.then(function() { 
    //generate your PDF here, since all the calls to Firebase have returned data
})
.catch(....);
```

Comment: Check the last script tag  it contains pdf generation functions

Comment: @LetsExplorer Are you sure? You call the function genPDF() from a  button, on line <button onclick="genPDF()">Generate</button> but I don't see the code for this function in your question. To be able to give you more details on how to solve your problem we need to know how events are chained.

Comment: For testing purpose, I have use the button tag.  My actual function is I am redirecting from the index.html to this current page. As us see last script  doesn't contain any function so that script runs directly and download the pdf

Comment: @LetsExplorer Ok, I understand. See the edit of my answer. You would then call the generatePDF() function when you load the page.

Comment: Which error??!! You should see it in the console. Can you copy it?

Comment: @LetsExplorer Ok, there was an error in my answer. I was calling then on the definition of the function... Can you try now. One point: I see that at lmine 182 you call genPDF. I do'nt think you should.